How to move/fix position of dropdown menu in html/css?
I have issue which is the dropdown menu is slightly misaligned or detached from the "Other" tab, I want it to be directly under the "Other" tab, with an arrow pointing to it.
HTML CODE:
    </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <div class="tooltip" id="otherTooltip">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleDropdown('otherDropdown')" class="navbar-link">Other</a>
              <span class="tooltiptext">Remain Taps</span>
            </div>
            <div id="otherDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="https://discord.gg/NmqGZjr2">Discord Server</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>

<script>
    // Toggle dropdown visibility and disable tooltip when shown
    function toggleDropdown(id) {
      const dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
      const tooltip = document.getElementById('otherTooltip');
      dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
      tooltip.classList.toggle("disabled"); // Disable tooltip when dropdown is shown
    }

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.navbar-link')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            document.getElementById('otherTooltip').classList.remove('disabled'); // Re-enable tooltip
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>

CSS CODE:
  <style>

  /* Parent container to handle relative positioning */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /* Changed from fixed to absolute */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 5px; /* Adjust to move dropdown away from the arrow */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Optional, to round corners */
  left: 0; /* Ensure dropdown aligns with parent */
  transform: translateX(0); /* Remove any extra shifting */
}

/* Add the arrow */
.dropdown-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%; /* Position above the dropdown */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f1f1f1 transparent; /* Match dropdown background color */
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
}

/* Add blue color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e0e7ff;
  color: #007bff;
}

/* Add blue color when active (clicked) */
.dropdown-content a:active {
  background-color: #c3dafe;
  color: #0056b3;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu */
.show {
  display: block;
}

  </style>

this how the issue looks like: Image For my Issue i'm facting it
i want fixs or solution for this issue.
it shows in place elsewhere when i clicking on it, so i want it to move to be below "Other" tab.

Solution to Dropdown Alignment Issue
To fix the misalignment and properly position the arrow, you can adjust the CSS for the dropdown arrow.
.dropdown-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%; 
  left: 10%; /* Adjusted to align with the "Other" tab */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f1f1f1 transparent; /* Match dropdown background color */
}

Hope this helps!
